# Import Data from Gmail into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have an email sent out on a daily basis that I need to pull data from to a Google Sheet.  I have read on this and found a solution that worked for other's, but I've been unable to get it to work on mine.  This is the code I've tried modifying:

```
function menu(e) {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Macros')
  .addItem('parse mail', 'email')
  .addToUi();
 }

function parseMail(body) {
var a=[];
var keystr="First Name     : ,Last Name      : ,Customer ID    : ,Invoice   : ";
var keys=keystr.split(",");
var i,p,r;
for (i in keys)  {
p=keys[i]+"\n([a-zA-Z0-9\ \,\.]*)\n";
r=new RegExp(p,"m");
try {a[i]=body.match(p)[1];}
catch (err) {a[i]="no match";}
 }
}

function email() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject: "Fwd: ARB Subscription*"');
var a=[];
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
  a[j]=parseMail(messages[j].getPlainBody());
  }
 }
  var nextRow=s.getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;
  var numRows=a.length;
  var numCols=a.length[0];
  s.getRange(nextRow,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(a);
}
```

I've tried modifying the code, but the error I am getting is Cannot convert Array to Object[][] Line 35.  any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Most probably `a` isn't a double array, or some lengths are less than others, log `a` to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Get the dimensions of the data range as below. 
Also, when you are setting the values on the range the size of two-dimensional array a must match the size of the range.

```
  var dataRange = s.getDataRange();
  var nextRow = dataRange.getLastRow() + 1;
  var numRows = dataRange.getNumRows();
  var numCols = dataRange.getNumColumns(); 

  s.getRange(nextRow,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(a);
```

Comment: Hey Matcheek,  I tried the code you entered above and I'm still getting the same error: Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 37 - refers to s.getRange.  Any ideas why?